# fixed point iteration

Tags: c++, numerical-methods

i am trying to find such  p,that for given function f(p),we have equality

p=f(p);
here is code

```
#include <iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;
float fixed(float x){
    return (float)(pow(x,3)-4*pow(x,2)-10);
}

int main(){
    float p=0.0;
    float p0=1.5;
    float tol=(float).001;
    int N=25;
    int i=1;
    while(i<N){
        p=(float)fixed(p0);
        if((p-p0)<tol){
          cout<<p<<endl;
          break;
        }
        i=i+1;
        p0=p;
        if(i>N){
          cout<<"solution not found ";
          break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

i have tried different  initial point,also different  tolerance,but result is very  nonsense -16 or -15.something,so what is wrong?is code correct?please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you simply don't have a situation in which the iterative algorithm is applicable. [See here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_point_%28mathematics%29#Attractive_fixed_points) for some conditions. Your function doesn't have an attractive fixed point near 1.5, and the algorithm diverges.

But why the numerics: Your function is `f(x) = x^3 - 4x - 10`, so solving `f(x) = x` amounts to finding the zeros of `f(x) - x`, and there is only one real zero near 5.35. Howevever, `f'(x)` at that point is very large, so even there the iterative algorithm isn't usable.

A numeric root-finding algorithm may be a more appropriate approach.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but probably using :

```
if(fabs(p-p0)<tol){
```

instead of :

```
if((p-p0)<tol){
```

will get you closer to where you want to go.

The reason is that all negative values are smaller than `.001`, so if the result of the function is a negative value (like in this case), you'll stop immediately.

Btw : this check :

```
if(i>N){
```

will never be true. You probably meant to use `==` or `>=` instead of `>`.

Answer (score 1):

```
fabs(p - p0) <= tol * fabs(p);
```

Is the correct formula for equal values. In case of special ranges you also have to care for NaN and Inf.

```
#include <limits>
#include <cfloat>

inline bool Equal(const double& x, const double& y)
{
  const int classX (_fpclass(x));

  if(classX != _fpclass(y)) {
    return false;
  }

  switch(classX) {
      case _FPCLASS_SNAN:  
      case _FPCLASS_QNAN: 
      case _FPCLASS_NINF: 
      case _FPCLASS_NZ  : 
      case _FPCLASS_PZ  : 
      case _FPCLASS_PINF: 
        return true;
        break;
      case _FPCLASS_NN  : 
      case _FPCLASS_ND  : 
      case _FPCLASS_PD  : 
      case _FPCLASS_PN  : 
      default:
        break;
  }

  return fabs(x - y) <= std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon() * fabs(x);
}
```